# как правильно указать путь? С++

Tags: c++, c, windows

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

    system(L"C:\\Users\\"__Имя Пользователя__"\\Downloads\\Hell.rar");
}
```

как вставить имя пользователя вместо **Имя Пользователя** ?

Comment: Получите значение из переменных среды. 
`UnicodeString Download = GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")+"\\Downloads";`.

Comment: ваш файл `***.rar` неисполняемый. он не сможет запуститься вообще.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Будет вызвано сопоставленное с данным расширением приложение...

Comment: @Harry .. не слышал о таком. наверное надо вызвать винодвскую тулзу  : `#include <shellapi.h> ShellExecute(NULL,_TEXT("open"),_TEXT("C:\\...\\Hell.rar"),NULL,NULL,1 );`

Comment: Даже `system` сработает... Но, конечно, `ShellExecute` более мощная функция.

Answer (score 5):

Вот типичный пример XY-проблемы. Ведь на самом деле вам надо найти не имя пользователя, а путь к папке загрузок, так? Но вы почему-то решили, что эта папка будет лежать именно по такому пути, с именем пользователя в папке `Users`, да еще и на диске `C:`... Долго бы вы там искали эту папку у меня на машине :)

Итак, получить папку загрузок можно с помощью функции [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN), примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj_core.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib,"Ole32")
#pragma comment(lib,"Shell32")

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    KNOWNFOLDERID id = FOLDERID_Downloads;
    wchar_t * path = nullptr;
    if (S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(id, 0, 0, &path))
    {
        wcout << path;
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(path);
}
```

P.S. А если хочется получить имя пользователя, то лучше всего использовать еще одну функцию WinAPI — [`GetUserName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew?source=recommendations)...

Comment: Допустим вот узнаю этот путь, а как мне открыть файл зная путь, меня это интересует только,. Не знаю, может я очень туплю конечно..

Comment: Указать в соответствующей функции имя файла...

Comment: типо такого: system(path); ? если нет, то я очень туплю и не понимаю... не бейте ногами

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "открыть"?

Comment: Ну, вот например кликаешь мышкой по rar архиву, и он отрывается, мне надо тоже самое

Comment: Тогда и `system` сработает; но по-хорошему лучше использовать [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea).

Comment: А как правильно вот написать эту строчку, чтобы открылся файл, который в загрузках?

Comment: Простите, не понимаю вопрос... диск:\папка\имя_файла — как можно иначе? Ну, можете относительный путь — если знаете свой текущий каталог, но смысл?... Или вы [со строками работать не умеете](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide)?

Comment: Да, не умею. Например, мне надо открыть файл, который находится в загрузках, как это сделать?

Comment: См. функции по ссылке. Это — азы языка, так что тут только — учебник и справочная система...